# display Current date in jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I want to generate current date in a html form and store that in the variable **currentDate**. when i write  it works fine if the user enters in the text area. But I want to store the current date(the user need not put it) and store it in the variable **currentDate**.

Comment: If it's the current date, why store it in the form. `new Date()` will get you the current date at server-side.

Comment: Best to take date at processing, ortherwise you will get the form generation date, the web page could be openned for days until someone submit so this date could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

use hidden variable in jsp If it is JSP

JSP HTML:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="currentDate" id="currentDate" value="<%=new Date()%>">
    <div id="div1"></di>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
function onLoad()
  {
   document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML ='<%=new Date()%>';
  }
```

use hidden variable in html If it is HTML , call this onLoad Form

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="currentDate" value="">
<div id="div1"></di>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
 function onLoad()
    {
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth();
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

    newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
    document.getElementById('currentDate').value=newdate;
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML =newdate;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks sunleo. Actually I need to display the date in the form as well. When user open the form, it should be like the following:

Date  2012/11/17

and I want to save it in the currentDate variable.

thanks.

Comment: @Biswajitdas Please do remaining work yourself .For you its enough.